# Intermittent sqlalchemy connectivity issue TCP Provider error 0x68

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, azure-functions, pyodbc

we have python function apps that connect to an Azure SQL database. It has been working fine up until late March, when we started to experience the following error intermittently:  "[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x68 (104) (SQLDriverConnect)"

It seems to happen more frequently on higher volume days, up to 15% of invocations experience this error. All research seems to point to network issues, however could not closing sql sessions cause this error as well, regardless of volume? Anything else that could case this issue?

Both AZSQL and function app are set to 1.2 TLS and pinned sqlalchemy to 1.4.47.

Answer (score 0):

If the Azure SQL connections are failing intermittently in your function app, Make sure your Function app is not running behind any Corporate Proxy, LAN or VPN or any Firewall connection is restricting the connection to Azure SQL.

I tried connecting to Azure SQL with Pyodbc in a restricted Firewall network LAN and received the below error even when the Instance name of SQL server, Database and the connection string is correct, With Client IP allowed in the Azure SQL server networking tab. Refer below:-

Error:-

[image]

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out.\r\n (258) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (258)')
```

When I tried connecting to my Azure SQL with the Client Machine without any Network restriction, I was able to query the Azure SQL database like below:-

**My Python code:-**

```py
import pyodbc

  

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'

'Server=tcp:<sqlservername>.database.windows.net,1433;'

'Database=<database-name>;'

'Uid=<username>;'

'Pwd=<password>')

  
  

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM StudentReviews')

  

for  i  in  cursor:

print(i)

  

cursor.close()

conn.close()
```

**Output:-**

[image]

In order to check the Azure SQL connection failure, Select your Azure SQL Server > Diagnose and Solve problems > Search for Connectivity: Troubleshoot DB Availability and Connection Errors > Select Connection timeouts or Dropped Connection and   perform the insights given in the solution like below:-

[image]

Select the start time of the Issue and paste your error code click on submit to get the insight:-

[image]

[image]

You can perform the insights from the results.

You can also run the Powershell script given in the recommendation to resolve and get insights on the intermittent timeouts or connectivity issues as given below:-

[image]

You can check the connectivity issues by running the scripts in SSMS to system tables like below:-

**Code:-**

```sql
SELECT start_time, end_time, database_name, sku, avg_cpu_percent, max_worker_percent, max_session_percent 
FROM sys.resource_stats;
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Troubleshoot common connection issues to Azure SQL Database - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues?view=azuresql)

[Error code 0x68 (104) (SQLGetData) · Issue #680 · mkleehammer/pyodbc · GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/680) By v-chojas

[pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)') · Issue #610 · mkleehammer/pyodbc · GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/610) By v-chojas